# Как установить горячие клавиши в python?

Tags: python, pynput

Я хочу установить горячие клавиши

Для этого я установил pynput и использую этот код

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, KeyCode, Listener
import sys
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab


# закончить код
def end_fun():
    print('end_fun')
    sys.exit()

def start_mouse():
    print('sssss')
    #input('input:')

def save_image():
    print('ffff')
    im = ImageGrab.grab()


# Код для горячих клавищ
combination_to_function = {
    frozenset([KeyCode(vk=49)]): end_fun, #1
    frozenset([KeyCode(vk=50)]): start_mouse,#2
    frozenset([KeyCode(vk=51)]): save_image,#3
}


# The currently pressed keys (initially empty)
pressed_vks = set()


def get_vk(key):
    return key.vk if hasattr(key, 'vk') else key.value.vk


def is_combination_pressed(combination):
    return all([get_vk(key) in pressed_vks for key in combination])


def on_press(key):
    vk = get_vk(key)  # Get the key's vk
    print(':vk =', vk, ':key =', key)
    pressed_vks.add(vk)  # Add it to the set of currently pressed keys
    for combination in combination_to_function:  # Loop through each combination
        if is_combination_pressed(combination):  # Check if all keys in the combination are pressed
            combination_to_function[combination]()  # If so, execute the function


def on_release(key):
    vk = get_vk(key)  # Get the key's vk
    pressed_vks.remove(vk)  # Remove it from the set of currently pressed keys


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Но проблема в том что когда я подключасторонниеие модули то почему то функция начинает воспроизводится вне зависимости от того какую клавишу я нажимаю
также код слетает когда я использую команду input. или сложную комбинацию букв
Как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки в вашем коде возникают, когда в коде сторонней библиотеке появляется `time.sleep(...)` или подлагивания при работе основного потока. Модуль pynput продолжает собирать очередь событий, даже если основной поток с Listener'ом занят какой-то другой задачей. Обойти эти ошибки можно, если создать свой цикл обработки, который будет напрямую обращаться к внутренней очереди pynput, а не занимать основной поток Listener'ом. Например pynput предлагает ещё один способ обработки событий - Events. Это - прямой доступ к очереди. Пример:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_down(key) # Колбек зажатой кнопки
    print("Pressed {}".format(key))
    input("input:") # input не вылетает и не зависает

def on_up(key) # Колбек отжатой кнопки
    print("Released {}".format(key))

while True: # Цикл вне блока with для постоянного обновления очереди
    with keyboard.Events() as events:
        event = events.get(1) # Ждём событие клавиши 1 секунду
        if event == None: # Если события не было, обновляем очередь
            continue
        elif isinstance(event, keyboard.Events.Press): # Кнопка зажата
            on_down(event.key)
        else: # Кнопка отжата
            on_up(event.key)
```